# Efficient Zoom At C#

Tags: c#, zooming

To zoom images in and out, there is a possible way to resize the pictureBox and showing image in strechmode. Although I can not use it efficiently becauce in general over 8x it gives storage error [think that a pictureBox has the Size(32k, 32k) it needs over 1GB memory !

Is there a special method, or should I zoom only the seen part of the image by using ImageClone ?

#### Update:

Here is the project at first try to zoom at the project [impossible, storage error] than delete the 41. line in form.cs :

```
pictureBox1.Image = youPicture;
```

After deleting this line, the program will work, please move the zoomed image.

Here is the link:  http://rapidshare.com/files/265835370/zoomMatrix.rar.html

Answer (score 3):

By using the matrix object and the transform property of your graphics object:

```
using(Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
{
    using(Bitmap youPicture = new Bitmap(yourPictureFile))
    {
        g.DrawImage(youPicture, 0, 0, 300, 100); //set the desired size

        //Now you need to create a matrix object to apply transformation on your graphic
        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.Scale(1.5f, 1.5f, MatrixOrder.Append); //zoom to 150%
        g.Transform = mat;

        g.DrawImage(youPicture, new Rectangle(...), 0, 0, youPicture.Width,
            youPicture.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you're right, I give him an alternative that is perflectly ok for his problem.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would just zoom the visible part as the rest is hidden anyway (and thus no use)

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140360/auto-sizing-zoom-on-an-image-in-net/1140538#1140538) to an earlier question.  You definitely don't want to zoom by making the image huge and showing only part of it - you'll run into the memory problem that you've already encountered.  Also, the stretch mode of a picture box doesn't use high-quality interpolation, so the result will look pretty crappy.

In the answer I linked here, I included a link to a C# project that shows you how to do this kind of zooming.

Update:  here is a [direct link](http://www.musigenesis.com/SO/JonbertZoom.zip) to the downloadable project.